# Ambiguous symbol error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
int ii, maxnum;  
for(ii=1; ii<=num-1; ii++) {  
    if(count[ii]>max) {  // the part where I get C2872 Ambiguous Symbol error  
        max = count[ii]; // the part where I get C2872 Ambiguous Symbol error  
        maxnum = ii;  
    }  
}
```

I've never gotten this error and this is frustrating.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your variable `max` conflicts with `std::max()`.  Try using a different name and it ought to fix that error.

Comment: It's reasons like this that make `using namespace std;` such a nightmare.

Comment: Rather than renaming `max` I would advice not to use the using directive `using namespace std;` for exactly this reason.

Comment: or explicitly define the namespace of max (::max)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not `std::max()` but these horrible `#define's` in `minwindef.h`:

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX

  #ifndef max
  #define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
  #endif

  #ifndef min
  #define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
  #endif

  #endif  /* NOMINMAX */
```

Use `#define NOMINMAX` in your project settings or `stdafx.h`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using `Intel RealSense 3D SDK` in `C++`. I had a `hand.cpp` and `hand.h` in my own code and when I had `using namespace Intel::RealSense;` it happen to be a conflict. In order to fix it, I removed `using namespace Intel::RealSense;` and added PXC to each class name related to the RealSense SDK.
Here are some example of new changes:
#

```
include "RealSense/SenseManager.h"
#include "RealSense/SampleReader.h"
#include "util_render.h"
#include "Visualizer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//using namespace Intel::RealSense;
PXCSenseManager *pp = PXCSenseManager::CreateInstance();
PXCCapture::Device *device;
PXCCaptureManager *cm;
```

and here's what the old code looked like:

```
#include "RealSense/SenseManager.h"
#include "RealSense/SampleReader.h"
#include "util_render.h"
#include "Visualizer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace Intel::RealSense;
SenseManager *pp = SenseManager::CreateInstance();
Capture::Device *device;
CaptureManager *cm;
```

After the changes, I didn't receive the following error anymore.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2872   'Hand': ambiguous symbol    OpenARK-SDK c:\openark\Object3D.h
```